# jQuery EasyUI Drag and Drop tree data output

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using jquery easyui drag and drop tree: http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php.
and I can successfully generate the tree structure from database data, and do some further drag and drop actions.

I wish to do some db updating actions while dragging and dropping, however, I cannot find the output format regarding the node structure, moreover I wish to know the point that I shall apply some .post codes for updating database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
onDrop: function(targetNode, source, point){  
       var targetId = $(target).tree('getNode', targetNode).id;  
       $.ajax({  
           url: '...',  
           type: 'post',  
           dataType: 'json',  
           data: {  
               id: source.id,  
               targetId: targetId,  
               point: point  
           }  
       });  
   }
```

See http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree5.php